# Anatomically Correct Meduza

Tags: creature-design, evolution, anatomically-correct

The Meduza is a strange creature: It is a quadrupedal tetrapod, with a human-like head with hair, a scaly reptilian body and tail, and elephantine legs. It is around the same size as a human. It lives in the sea, but can come onto land and move quite effectively. The most notable traits are the serpentine heads  on the feet and at the end of the tail, all of which produce a venom that can kill a human

How could such a creature evolve?

Comment: it evolved from the medusa, but being from the balkans they spelled it with a Z

Comment: @Green: She is from the Balkan**z**. If she were from the Balkan**s** she would be called Medu**s**a.

Comment: @AlexP scuză-mă Alexandru

Comment: so, it's a four legged creature with four legs?

Comment: @ths What do you mean?

Comment: quadrupedal tetrapod is a redundant pleonasm.

Comment: @ths: Actually, humans for example are bipedal tetrapods without feathers, and chickens are bipedal tetrapods with feathers; snakes and caecilians are legless tetrapods; and cetaceans are tetrapods too.

Comment: You mention that the creature lives in the sea - is that near the coast in shallows or deeper? None of the features that you mention supports a deep sea dweller.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza It lives in shallower regions

Comment: The meduza doesn't have a gaze that turns people into stone?

Comment: @nullpointer No, that's Medusa

Comment: VTC:NAW. If you read the [tag:anatomically-correct] tag wiki, you'll be linked to the Anatomically Correct Series page, which has as one of its rules, "the ACS is now limited to questions about documented myths and legends of Humanity and creatures thoroughly designed (other than lacking anatomical fulfillment) for a fictional world of the OP's own creation." Further, the ACS if for ***describing an evolved creature***. It is not for explaining the process of evolution (which appears to be what you're asking), which is opinion-based.

Comment: @JBH How is a creature's evolution opinion based?

Comment: @JBH And why doesn't this question fit the definition of the ACS, or the bounds of what is allowable on this site?

Comment: @IchthysKing ACS is specifically looking to a manifestation of a creature. In other words, a description of what that creature could physiologically be that rationalizes its existence. That is not what you asked for. (And evolution is ***always*** opinion based, even for a non-fictional creature. You're treating the study of evolution as if it's a mature science that can be objectively applied to arbitrary fictional creatures. It cannot.)

Comment: @JBH If evolution was inherently based on opinion, it wouldn't be the 12th most popular tag on the site

Comment: Sorry, @IchthysKing, but asking questions about how a specific evolutionary pressure works is very different from asking how a creature can evolve - which questions are routinely closed as opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening: *a quadrupedal tetrapod, with a human-like head with hair, a scaly reptilian body and tail, and elephantine legs. It is around the same size as a human. It lives in the sea, but can come onto land and move quite effectively.*

I could get less serious and post [Spongebobia Encyclopedia](https://spongebob.fandom.com/wiki/Human_dinosaurs?file=SpongeBob_in_RandomLand_182.png) and show some :d

**Gigantism in humans**

I think a creature like this could have evolved from humans, in a few stages. To begin, the world ends as we know it. Some mass extinction event. Only a few humans survive the blow, but they lost their language and civilisation within a few generations.. Humans returned to animal state and went vegetarian, because nearly all birds, fish, mammals and insects died. This also meant: little competition left.. the humans formed herds and found a suitable niche. Humans  started to prosper as a species, which lasted for about a million years. In some places with plenty of food, the humans developed elephantine legs, as part of [gigantism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_gigantism). The upper body grew too.. A long tail evolved, to keep the balance. Elephantine humans, a gentle and slow moving species. At some point, bipedal reversed to quadrupedal, to carry the increased weight. Same time, many new species would appear and humans had to weaponize against predators again. They developed some features that *appear* dangerous, but  cost little extra energy: fake heads with teeth, a multicolor reptile-like skin.. large claws.. and fierce spikes on the tail. Voilá Homo Meduzae !

**Aftermath**

Within another million years, Homo Meduzae reduced in size, became bipedal again, developed language and civilisation. They took off to the moon, and eventually left some rubble and ruins on Jupiter's moon Ganymedes. They disappeared from earth, not unlike the scenario presented in James P. Hogan's trilogy.

Answer (score 1):

**It evolved from a komodo dragon**

The existing creature that best matches your description is a [komodo dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_dragon). They already have roughly the same size you described, live in the shallows of coastal regions and are apex predators.

Then two different evolution processes happened to this existing "body plan" to make them your Meduza:

- Evolving a symbiotic relationship with serpents to form the serpentine heads at the feet and tail
- Parallel evolution to a human-like head -> it will possibly not be *exactly* human-like, especially in the nose and mouth region, and with thin scales or barbs in place of actual hair